# Last bottles are extremely cloudy in my first homebrew bottling

Tags: yeast, beer, ale, cloudy, pale

I've just bottled my first batch and all bottles seemed fine, little bit cloudy but seemed okay.
Last few bottles are extremely cloudy and almost look just like yeast. Is this still safe to use or do I discard it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you ferment and bottle? Is this from a kit with a bucket and a faucet?

Comment: Danny, please remember to accept an answer if you think your question is answered well - which it seems to be,

Comment: Some people use the 'dregs' for cooking e.g. in a stew, where the beer doesn't have to be so wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

It's safe to drink. There are plenty of articles that claim that yeast is actually healthy (e.g., [healthline.com](https://www.healthline.com/health/brewers-yeast), [webmd](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-715/brewers-yeast)).

It may not taste great and look too cloudy. If that bothers you, you can try to filter the beer. Afterwards you need to add sugar and possibly more yeast to get bottle fermentation going, or you'll end up with flat beer.

For the next batch I'd recommend you bring your fermenting vessel to a table or kitchen counter. Let it sit a few hours so that all trub stirred from moving can settle again. Then rack into a different vessel, like a bottling bucket (with a spigot). Let that sit a few hours again. (Side effect: diacetyl rest.)

Bottle from that vessel, but don't tilt it. The bottling bucket usually has the spigot a little bit above the bottom of the bucket so that the last few millimeters don't go through the spigot. If you are using a racking cane, you can put a little plastic cap on the bottom, so that it doesn't suck in the sediment. (You can improvise with steel wool, which will keep the cane off the bottom of the vessel while letting liquid through.) That way you leave the sediment in the bucket.

Comment: Good technique is important but there is always a bit of a conflict between getting the best yield and the best product in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely safe to drink, just a higher level of yeast in suspension.

I would recommend to mark those bottles and see if they still look different after 4-6 weeks conditioning undisturbed in the bottle - preferably in a nice cool place.

Most likely the yeast will settle out but those ones will end up with a thicker layer of sediment than the others. Check to see if there is a flavour difference compared to the others - you might even find you like it.

Comment: +1 for marking any 'suspect' or different bottles.